# How to fix "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous."

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running this code as an exercise to use geom_col instead of geom_bar, and I would like to understand what is causing the error mentioned in the title of my post.

```r
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)

flights %>%
    group_by(carrier) %>%
    count() ->
    flights_by_carrier_counted

ggplot(data = flights, mapping = aes(x = factor(carrier), y=flights_by_carrier_counted)) +
  geom_col()
```

Comment: You are using a data frame as the value of the y-axis variable, when you should be using a column name from a data frame. I think you want `ggplot(flights_by_carrier_counted, aes(x = carrier, y = n)) +
  geom_col()`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks! BTW, I'm surprised that the new column was named "n" automatically (rather than something like "Var2") as if R knew that it was the result of a count. Not sure if I actually like this behavior :)

Comment: The `count()` function has a `name = ` argument (see `?count`), its default value is `n`. Makes sense since `n` is typically used to mean "number of observations".